# Build Failure error in Netbeans maven plugins

Tags: java, json, rest, maven, netbeans

I am using netbeans for creating my first RESTful API, Java with JSON to write a code. I tried to create the project but it gives this error.

A build failure error is encountered. It says :

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:2.3:generate (default-cli) 
    on project standalone-pom: Archetype io.dropwizard.archetypes:java-simple:0.8.1-rc3-SNAPSHOT is not configured
    Property name is missing.
```

More detailed is listed on this pastebin: `http://pastebin.com/N1KtGypW`

I tried to follow help topic `Project properties: Maven Project` to troubleshoot the issue, but were unable to fix it.

Please suggest measures to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the build output:

> cd /home/aruns/NetBeansProjects; JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
>   /home/aruns/netbeans-8.0.2/java/maven/bin/mvn
>   -DarchetypeGroupId=io.dropwizard.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=java-simple -DarchetypeVersion=0.8.1-rc3-SNAPSHOT -DarchetypeRepository=https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots
>   -DgroupId=com.mycompany -DartifactId=MyDropwizRESTfulProject -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=com.mycompany.mydropwizrestfulproject -Dbasedir=/home/aruns/NetBeansProjects -Dshaded=true **-Dname=** -Ddescription=null -Darchetype.interactive=false --batch-mode --update-snapshots archetype:generate

The option -Dname property is not set (in bold above) and it is this option I think Maven is complaining about.

I assume you created the project from the Netbeans 'Create From Archetype' and you used 'io.dropwizard.archetypes'. The window that comes up there is a table with 'Additional Creation Properties'. You need to specify the name in this I think.

Comment: Yes I used this link to create the project: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483883/how-to-use-dropwizard-in-netbeans-project